# Google Sheets - Script to move constant file names to another folder

Tags: google-apps-script, move

I would like to upload files from google drive to one drive separate folders based on part of the file name. For instance the files would be: FLRT0001, FLRT0002 and ETC. The constant part of the name is FLRT. Is there a way that google script can move the files that contain FLRT to move into another folder?

The script that I am using now, moves a file from a folder into another folder without any duplication.

Code is as below,

```
> function CopyFiles() {
> var srcFldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("***ID***");
> var srcFiles = srcFldr.getFiles();
> var desFldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("***ID***");
> var desFiles = desFldr.getFiles();
> var dfnA = [];
> var key = "fileIDs";
> var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
> var property = scriptProperties.getProperty(key);    // Retrieve fileIDs property
> Get array of fileId, or empty array if no file has been copied before:
> var arrayIDs = property ? JSON.parse(property) : []; 
> while (desFiles.hasNext()) {
> var df = desFiles.next();
> dfnA.push(df.getName());
>   }
> while (srcFiles.hasNext()) {
> var sf = srcFiles.next();
> Check not only file name, but also whether fileId has been stored before:
> if (dfnA.indexOf(sf.getName()) == -1 && arrayIDs.indexOf(sf.getId()) == - 1) {
> sf.makeCopy(sf.getName(), desFldr);
> arrayIDs.push(sf.getId()); // Add fileId to array of IDs
>     }
>   }
> scriptProperties.setProperty(key, JSON.stringify(arrayIDs)); // Store updated array
> }
```

I have not tried anything and I am stuck where to find information on this. Please help and thank you very much!

Comment: Yes it's possible but it depends on several things: 1/ where are the files initially ? In the same folder ? Anywhere on Drive ? 2/ When should the files be moved ? Everytime a new one is added to Drive ? (complicated) Once a day if there are any (easier) ? Manually when you launch the script ? (very easy)

Comment: Have you checked on using [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) or [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfiles), iterating through them and move the ones you are interested?